# Any news of the DevShock SMPP Component?

Tags: .net, sms, components

I am maintaining a program that uses the DevShock SMPP component for .NET.  I have noticed though that for a long time (at least 6 months) the [website](http://www.devshock.com/) has a "New Site Under Construction" notice, saying that it will be ready by September 2008.
Does anyone know if it will ever be back?
Does anyone know of another free comparable library/component for .NET?

Update December 2009 - Website now says a new web page coming December 2009

Comment: I'd say not, judging by the tumble weed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [aboutus.org](http://www.aboutus.org/DevShock.com), below is the contact info of the developer :)

aa@pla.net.py

Gral Garay 613 E/ Lillo y Bertoni
Asuncion, PARAGUAY

+595 971230094, Fax: +1 571 434 4620

Answer (score 1):

IP*Works has one: http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/smpp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've still got a download of the file, should anyone want it:

http://sites.google.com/site/freesmsuk/smpp/devshock.smpp.zip

Regards

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still on the hunt for a replacement library. I've just come across another project at Sourceforge (EasySMPP - http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/). Not sure about the code yet (just about to dig in), but you might get some mileage.